# Entity Framework and Mysql fail to insert

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to insert row to mySql db and I'm getting this error.

```
   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT
 `groups_users`.`groupID`, 
 `groups_u' at line 1
```

The Code is

```
        groups_users ug = new groups_users();
        ug.groupID = 1;
        ug.userID = 1;
        ug.isDeleted = false;
        ug.created = DateTime.Now;
        ctx.groups_users.Add(ug);

        ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the larger context of the code (the containing method)

Comment: hi Alex Zheludov i am also getting same error here could you please show me example here how you fixed that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it. 
Had issue in edmx file. all fields were set to be entity keys.