# Upload the excel data using entitframework to mysql db

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

When uploading the data in mysql database using entityframework below error occured:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT
     `outstanding_master`.`CustomerID`, 
     `outstanding_master`.`Na' at line 1

```
   foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                //object value = null;

                outstanding_master master = new outstanding_master();
                {
                    master.CustomerID = dr[0].ToString();
                    //   EntityKey orderKey =
                    // new EntityKey("UploadsEntities.outstanding_master", "CustomerID", master.CustomerID);
                    master.Name = dr[1].ToString();
                    master.PhoneNumber = Convert.ToInt64(dr[2].ToString());
                    master.Address = dr[3].ToString();
                    master.ServiceProviderID = Convert.ToInt32(dr[4].ToString());
                    master.TotalDue = dr[5].ToString();
                    master.LastPaidAmount = dr[6].ToString();
                    master.LastPaidDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[7].ToString());
                    master.OutStandingDescription = dr[8].ToString();
                    master.longitudeandlatitude = dr[9].ToString();
                }
                db.outstanding_master.Add(master);
                  db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: similar problem is here but not cleared http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165115/entity-framework-and-mysql-fail-to-insert?answertab=active#tab-top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here In my database for  outstanding_master table not having the  primary key when i added hat it's working fine.